# Laravel eloquent presenting Input::get values as?

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am working on a standard user login system, but something is really odd this time.

I get the input from a form, that a controller should validate. I save the input using Laravel's Input::only() method into $input variable and everything is saved, because if I var_dump($input), it displays an array with the exact values I POST-ed. But when I do Auth::attempt($input), even if there is a matching record in the database I get nothing.

I tried dumping the query and this is what I get:

```
string 'select * from `users` where `login` = ? limit 1' (length=47)
```

This is what my method looks like:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::only('login', 'password');

    // return $input;

    if (Auth::attempt($input)) {
        return View::make('pages.admin');
    }

    else{
        return 'nope!';
    }
}
```

I also tried doing the validation manually, storing the inputs into their respective variables and selecting it through the

```
$user = User::where('login', '=', $login)
    ->where('password', '=', $password)
    ->firstOrFail();
```

and the query I dumped doing this is

```
'select * from `users` where `login` = ? and `password` = ? limit 1'
```

I have no idea what is wrong with it, did you run into something like that? Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I identified the problem by troublehooting it furtherly. If I hardcode the login and password the Auth::attempt() passes, so the problem is, that somehow the Auth::attempt() is not picking the input as a string probably...or something like that

Comment: Can you post what var_export returns for your $input just before you pass it to attempt() ?

Comment: of yourse, thank you for engagement; this is the var_export: 
array ( 'login' => 'foobar', 'password' => 'foobar', )

Comment: @phobos2077 hmm...there is a comma after that...could that be the issue? But how to get rid of that? o_O

Comment: Is "foobar" a correct password? Maybe you have incorrect input from your form.

Comment: I am 100% sure, that foobar is the correct password...it is not translating the varaibles to SQL query generated by eloquent for some reason :/

Comment: That is actually normal, because UserProvider only searches your user by "login" field and then calls getAuthPassword() to get the password and uses hasher to check password. Maybe you saved plaintext password (instead of hashed) in your database?

Comment: ou yeaaah :) that was exactly the issue. Stupid me :/ thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel Docs [Security](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security) :

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
{
return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```